# How to set multiple data-toggle for a link in bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a link and I want to set a bootstrap tooltip for it and aI want it to show a bootstrap modal too.
To show a modal the code is this:

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Show</a>
```

And the following would make a bootstrap tooltip:

```
<a data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-original-title='Hello' href="#"></a>
```

Now how to combine it.Combine means having a link that shows modal and has a bootstrap tooltip too?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found the issue:

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" rel="tooltip" data-original-title='Hello'>Show</a>
```

Thats all.

Comment: I need to follow @Deepak Yadav step `$("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();`

Comment: @DoanTran Yeah. His sentence is true but its not the true answer of the question. That step is needed but the question was how to set multiple data-toggle.

Comment: @HamidReza even your answer doesn't solve the problem, Yes your solution works with "tooltip" but for "popover" it doesn't work, so I have to go with F.L. answer.

Comment: $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip(); did not work for me. Wrapping element using another span worked.

Answer (score 23):

I would rather use a wrapping element like this:

```
<span data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hello">
    <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Show</a>
</span>
```

This seems more straightforward to me. See this bootply: http://www.bootply.com/zqJRSAjSuQ

Comment: Tip : If you find some design issues then try to toggle tooltip and model.

Comment: Simple and no JavaScript changes. Readability does not change either. good one.

Comment: Even though this bloats the markup a tiny bit, this is still by far the most desirable  option yet! 

The javascript invocation using more or less obscure selectors are definately hacks that are going to cost on the readability => maintanance in the long run!

Comment: This is a great answer, but due to Bootstrap navbar CSS selectors it didn't work for me.  For anyone else doing this, I had to put the `<span>` inside the `<a>` link.

Answer (score 14):

you  dont need use `data-toggle` for tooltip, you can change to you want, like `data-tt` for example:

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-tt="tooltip" title="hi">Show</a>
```

And initialize in javascript:

```
$("[data-tt=tooltip]").tooltip();
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61ky7h2m/6/)

Answer (score 13):

U may also need to to initialize it :
I needed to initialize it at bottom of page.

```
        $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
```

Answer (score 11):

Add a data attribute to the element:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-hover="tooltip" title="Click to Open" data-placement="right" href="#"></a>
```

And initialize in javascript:

```
$("[data-hover='tooltip']").tooltip();
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using a `div` instead of a `span` element when the tooltip is misplaced ...

Based on F.L.'s answer, this worked for me:

```
<div data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hello">
    <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Show</a>
</div>
```